# Correct Java RDD structure for Spark MLlib Model Predict?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've got a trained [`MatrixFactorizationModel`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel) via [`ALS.train(...)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS%24) and now I'm trying to use it to predict some ratings like so:

```
JavaRDD<Rating> predictions = model.predict(usersProducts.rdd())
```

Where `usersProducts` is built from an existing Ratings dataset like so:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,Integer> usersProducts = testRatings.map(
  new PairFunction<Rating, Integer, Integer>() {
    public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> call(Rating r) throws Exception {
      return new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(r.user(), r.product());
    }
  }
);
```

The problem is that `model.predict(...)` doesn't like `usersProducts`, claiming that the method doesn't accept an `RDD` of type `Tuple2` however the docs show the method signature as follows:

```
def predict(usersProducts: RDD[(Int, Int)]): RDD[Rating]
```

Am I missing something? The JavaRDD is just a list of `Tuple2` elements, which would match the method signature but the compile is complaining.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the objects are supposed to be `int` and not `Integer` so the appropriate syntax is as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<Object,Object> usersProducts = testRatings.map(
    new PairFunction<Rating, Object, Object>() {
        public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(Rating r) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(r.user(), r.product());
        }
    }
);
```

So I had to generalize and use `Object` instead. And then the `predict` method should look like the following:

```
JavaRDD<Rating> predictions = model.predict(usersProducts.rdd()).toJavaRDD();
```